# Find all next input fields

Tags: jquery

My form will automatically calculate the remaining balance when the user enters payment in the input field. For example, assume the total is $1000 and the user wants to divide this into 3 payments. He will put $500 in the first payment field then remaining $500 will be distributed equally among the next payment fields. $250 each. If the user wants $200 for the second payment then $300 will be inserted in the last payment field. I can't get the jquery find next input fields.

This is my form

```
<div id="payment-terms-fields">
  <div class="payment-rows">
    <div>
       <input type="text" name="payment[]" class="payment-terms">
       <span class="payment_term_sign">%</span>
    </div>
    <div><select class="term">....</select></div>
  </div> 

  <div class="payment-rows">
    <div>
       <input type="text" name="payment[]" class="payment-terms">
       <span class="payment_term_sign">%</span>
    </div>
    <div><select class="term">....</select></div>
  </div> 



</div>
```

This is my jquery to find the next input fields

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".payment-terms", function() {
 var nextFields = $(this).parents("#payment-terms-fields").find('input.payment-terms').not(this);
});
```

Above code finds all input fields except the `this` How do I find next input fields?

Comment: Is `var nextFields` wrapped in a function? If not, then `this` may be referring to another element or the `window`...it's all about the context. Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: No, it's not. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it!

Not sure how efficient it is or if it can be improved but this worked for me in this fiddle:

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".payment-terms").css("background", "#00ff00");
```

Full demo in this fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/rtpHarry/8fmXz/

Answer (score 2):

You can descend directly from the ID, because IDs are unique on a page. No need to use parents().

```
$('#payment-terms-fields').find('input.payment-terms').not(this).next()
```

Comment: This didn't make any change. It's selecting all input fields again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `$(this).next().find('input.payment-terms')` ?